# Set usergroup and persmissions ftp folder back to default

Tags: ftp

I tried to create a new ftp user via the commandline. But I did something wrong and now I can access the server via FTP but I can't see any files. It doesn't make any sense wich user I'm using.

```
ls -la
drwxr-xr-x 13 root ftp 4096 2012-03-30 09:47 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 web6 ftp 4096 2012-03-26 09:28 ..
drwxr-xr-x  4 web6 ftp 4096 2012-03-26 13:31 actions
drwxr-xr-x  2 web6 ftp 4096 2012-03-26 11:46 bin
-rwxr-xr-x  1 web6 ftp 1520 2012-03-24 23:32 changelog.txt
drwxr-xr-x  2 web6 ftp 4096 2012-03-26 13:30 css
drwxr-xr-x  8 web6 ftp 4096 2012-03-24 22:43 external
-rwxr-xr-x  1 web6 ftp  333 2012-03-26 15:12 .htaccess
drwxr-xr-x  3 web6 ftp 4096 2012-02-27 15:07 images
-rwxr-xr-x  1 web6 ftp 1606 2012-03-26 21:25 index.php
drwxr-xr-x  2 web6 ftp 4096 2012-02-18 13:20 js
drwxr-xr-x  2 web6 ftp 4096 2012-02-03 00:34 layout
drwxr-xr-x  2 web6 ftp 4096 2012-03-29 23:35 library
drwxr-xr-x  2 web6 ftp 4096 2012-03-30 09:47 log
-rwxr-xr-x  1 web6 ftp  396 2012-03-24 15:04 menu.php
drwxr-xr-x  2 web6 ftp 4096 2012-03-30 12:01 python
drwxr-xr-x  2 web6 ftp 4096 2012-03-23 10:51 todo
```

I can't see any dirs and files because I changed the groupowner or I the rights of the groupowner of the ftp dir.

How can I set the ownership of the files back to default so I can access the files via FTP again?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution it would be to review history and see what you changed .(history command)

If you haven't applied the rights recursively , then you can see the rights assigned to the files / and ownership and apply them again to the root folders of the FTP .

Alex H